# How to control parallel execution in Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, parallel-processing

I'm trying to execute a script that I developed for data transformation in Oracle.

I have a table with a very large amount of data and I want to split that data into another table based on a condition and then delete the affected rows from the original table.

My approach was to use create table as select for the second table, then the same to the first table with the condition inverted. Finally I truncated the original table and moved back the data to the original from the temporary table. Like so:

```
create table data_reject as
select a, b, c
from table_original
where a in (select criteria from aux_table)
/
```

then

```
create table data_aux as
select a, b, c
from table_original
where a NOT in (select criteria from aux_table)
/
```

finally I would do

```
truncate table data_original
/
```

and

```
insert into table_original (a, b, c)
select a, b, c
from table_aux
/
```

My problem is I placed a parallel hint on all the select and create table commands, and it appears that one statement is issued, and the next one starts executing without waiting for the first statement to end execution.

This leads to the original table losing all its data before the script has time to populate the other two tables.

This script was executed with the command

```
alter session enable parallel dml
```

How can I prevent one command from starting before the previous one ends execution?

This is what the script looks like:
      -- create temp table
      create table id_loc_rejected_temp parallel 32 nologging as
         with
            id_hier as
               (select hierarchy7_key as id from id_hierarchy),
            loc_hier as
               (select hierarchy6_key as loc from loc_hierarchy)

```
     select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
            id_key,
            loc_key
       from sls a
      where a.id_key not in (select key from merch_hier)
     union all

     select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
            id_key,
            loc_key
       from sls a
      where a.loc_key not in (select store from loc_hier)
     union all

     select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
            id_key,
            loc_key
       from id_loc_rejected_previous a
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'First filter. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  --add more filters
  insert /* + APPEND PARALLEL (id_loc_rejected_temp, 32) */
    into id_loc_rejected_temp(id_key,
                                loc_key)
        with
           store_repl as
              (select /* + PARALLEL (t, 32) */ id_key as id, loc_key as store from srep t)

        select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
               id_key,
               loc_key
          from sls a
         where (a.id_key, a.loc_key) not in (select id, store from store_repl)
        union all

        select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
               id_key,
               loc_key
          from inv a
         where (a.id_key, a.loc_key) not in (select id, store from store_repl)

  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Second filter. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  -- remove duplicates
  create table id_loc_rejected parallel 32 nologging as
  select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */ distinct id_key, loc_key from id_loc_rejected_temp a
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Transformed temp table into final table. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  drop table id_loc_rejected_temp
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Dropped id loc rejected temp table')
  /

  -- Create rejected data tables
  create table sls_rejected parallel 32 nologging as
        select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
               id_key,
               id_level,
               loc_key,
               loc_level,
               date1,
               ticket,
               units
          from sls a
         where (a.id_key, a.loc_key) in (select id_key, loc_key from id_loc_rejected)
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Sales rejected created. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  -- inventory reject table
  create table inv_rejected parallel 32 nologging as
        select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
               id_key,
               id_level,
               loc_key,
               loc_level,
               date1,
               ticket,
               units
          from inv a
         where (a.id_key, a.loc_key) in (select id_key, loc_key from id_loc_rejected)
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Inventory rejected created. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  -- stockouts reject table
  create table oos_rejected parallel 32 nologging as
        select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
               id_key,
               id_level,
               loc_key,
               loc_level,
               date1,
               ticket,
               flag
          from oos a
         where (a.id_key, a.loc_key) in (select id_key, loc_key from id_loc_rejected)
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Stockout rejected created. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  -- store replenishment reject table
  create table stg_ro_st_re_rejected parallel 32 nologging as
        select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
               id_key,
               loc_key,
               review
          from srep a
         where (a.id_key, a.loc_key) in (select id_key, loc_key from id_loc_rejected)
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Store replenishment parameters rejected created. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  -- now, create temp tables to hold the rest of the data (what we want to keep)
  -- sales temp table
  create table sls_tmp parallel 32 nologging as
        select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
               id_key,
               id_level,
               loc_key,
               loc_level,
               date1,
               ticket,
               ticket
          from sls a
         where (a.id_key, a.loc_key) not in (select id_key, loc_key from id_loc_rejected)
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Sales temp created. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  -- Store replenishmment temp table
  create table stg_ro_store_repl_tmp parallel 32 nologging as
        select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
               id_key,
               loc_key,
               review
          from srep a
         where (a.id_key, a.loc_key) not in (select id_key, loc_key from id_loc_rejected)
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Store replenishment temp created. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /
  commit
  /

  -- truncate original tables and reinsert

  -- Final Sales
  truncate table sls
  /

  insert /* + APPEND PARALLEL (sls, 32) */
    into sls(id_key,
                        id_level,
                        loc_key,
                        loc_level,
                        date1,
                        ticket,
                        ticket)
              (
                 select /* + PARALLEL (a, 32) */
                        id_key,
                        id_level,
                        loc_key,
                        loc_level,
                        date1,
                        ticket,
                        ticket
                   from sls_tmp a
              )
  /

  insert into debug_msg values(sysdate, 'Sales reinserted. Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows')
  /

  commit
  /
  drop table sls_tmp
  /
```

Comment: Parallel DML would not cause one statement to be executed until the prior statement completed.  Either that is not what you are seeing or there are some important pieces of information missing from your question.

Comment: Hi Justin, I say the commands executed almost immediately because it's a very large script with inserts into a log table. Immediately, 3 out of 10 messages were inserted, including the very last one. The commands take a long time to execute by themselves (15, 20 + minutes). I terminated the command before it was done (2 minutes of execution) because it was spooling by mistake.

Comment: Also, the table was truncated before the new tables were created.

Comment: Maybe this was a mistake, but the commands were terminated with a newline and a / in a line of its own, without the semicolon.

Comment: A script containing a series of SQL statements run by `SQL*Plus`, SQL Developer, TOAD, or any other "normal" application will not start executing statement N until statement N-1 has completed.  Using parallel DML will not change this fact.  It would be possible to have a script that submits a series of jobs where parallel DML would be likely to affect relative timings but that would involve lots of calls to `dbms_job` or `dbms_scheduler`.  Theoretically, there could be a client application that would do that automatically but it's hard to envision.

Comment: I agree with Justin that this is extremely unusual behavior for a client.  I've never seen a program that would automatically run queries asynchronously like this.  Can you add information on what client you're using?

Comment: Hello Jon. It's being run in ksh through an sqlplus command.

Comment: Found the version: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri Apr 22 13:03:32 2016

Comment: Sorry, this is the right one:
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Apr 22 13:05:07 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the select statements in the script. Some of them had blank lines for organization inside and these lines made sqlplus think it had to execute two commands instead of one.

This made the very long commands fail completely, while the next commands had basically nothing to do or failed too.

The other problem was the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` inside the insert, it made it look like only some of the inserts were being performed while others lagged behind.

Finally, I broke the script apart, executing one step at a time and everything worked fine.